# Floyd-Warshall algorithm on a directed graph in which every edge's length is either -1, 0, or 1

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I'm taking the [Algorithms: Design and Analysis II](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/course-v1:Engineering+Algorithms2+SelfPaced/about) course, and one of the questions is as follows:

> Suppose we run the Floyd-Warshall algorithm on a directed graph `G =
>   (V,E)` in which every edge's length is either -1, 0, or 1. Suppose
>   further that `G` is strongly connected, with at least one `u-v` path
>   for every pair `u,v` of vertices. The graph `G` may or may not have a
>   negative-cost cycle. How large can the final entries `A[i,j,n]` be, in
>   absolute value? Choose the smallest number that is guaranteed to be a
>   valid upper bound. (As usual, `n` denotes `|V|`.) [WARNING: for this
>   question, make sure you refer to the implementation of the
>   Floyd-Warshall algorithm given in lecture, rather than to some
>   alternative source.]
>
> - 2^n
> - n -1
> - n^2
> - infinity

The lecture video that's been referred to is on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cBHwPjDZxg). For reference, the algorithm is as follows:

```
for k = 1 to n
  for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to n
      A[i,j,k] = min {A[i,j,k-1], A[i,k,k-1] + A[k,j,k-1]}
```

The correct answer is the first one, `2^n`, and the hint says it can be proved by induction. I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the graph where all nodes are connected to all other nodes with an edge of length `-1`.

The induction can be done on k. Let's prove the following expression:

`A[i,j,k] = -2 ** k`

For `k = 0`, `A[i,j,k] = -1` (by definition of graph). So, the base condition checks out.

Now, `A[i,j,k] = min(A[i,j,k-1], A[i,k,k-1] + A[k,j,k-1])`.
Using the inductive hypothesis, all the terms on the right will be `-2 ** (k - 1)`.

Hence, `A[i,j,k] = -2 ** k` and `abs(A[i,j,n]) = 2 ** n`.

Comment: It seems that if you take edge lengths as 1, you'll come to the same result without having to take the abs.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, No, since in that case the minimum of 2 ** (k - 1) and 2 ** (k - 1) + 2 ** (k - 1) will be 2 ** (k - 1). Negative edges are necessary for the blowup in *shortest distance*.

Comment: The inductive hypothesis can be assumed for `k`, and if you prove for `k + 1`, the RHS is `2^k`. It doesn't make sense to suddenly take abs of `A[i,j,n]`, because there's nothing like that in the algorithm. It seems made up just to fit the proof.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I think you are missing the point. If all edges were 1, the shortest distance between any two points will always be 1. 2 ** k wouldn't make sense because it's not shorted than simply the edge connecting the two points. With negative edges, the shortest distance is unbounded, which is what results in the large numbers.

Comment: Who said there's an edge between every pair of vertices? "G is strongly connected, with at least one u-v *path* for every pair u,v of vertices". "path" doesn't mean a single edge.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Ok, in that case the shortest distance would be n since a shortest path can only contain all the nodes at worst. If you still can't picture it, try drawing a simple graph of a few nodes and see if there is a shortest path of the order 2 ** n.